# Clearing previously entered edittext data automatically on checking a checkbox

Tags: android

I have 3 checkboxes and 2 edittexts. When the user checks one checkbox and enters data in one edittext calculations take place. If i check another checkbox the edittext values should automatically clear. However the data in the edittexts exist even after i check other checkboxes.I tried finish() which shuts the application. Any idea how can this be achieved without closing the app?

Sorry if this question sounds weird. Iam just learning android
Thank you.

code for my onCheckedChangedListener

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton predictionChkView, boolean isPredictionChecked)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        switch(predictionChkView.getId())
        {
        case R.id.chkLastMileage1:

                                        isChkLastMileage1=true;
                                        chkLastMileage5.setChecked(false);
                                        chkLastMileage10.setChecked(false);
                                        ETPredictKm.setText("");
                                        ETPredictFuelQty.setText("");

                                        break;

        case R.id.chkLastMileage5:
                                        isChkLastMileage5=true;
                                        chkLastMileage1.setChecked(false);
                                        chkLastMileage10.setChecked(false);
                                        ETPredictKm.setText("");
                                        ETPredictFuelQty.setText("");
                                        break;
        case R.id.chkLastMileage10:

                                        isChkLastMileage10 =true;
                                        chkLastMileage1.setChecked(false);
                                        chkLastMileage5.setChecked(false);
                                        ETPredictKm.setText("");
                                        ETPredictFuelQty.setText("");
                                        break;
        }

    }

Code for the onFocusChangedListener

public void onFocusChange(View predictionFocusView, boolean hasPredictionETFocus) 
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FuelStoredInfo predictInfo = new FuelStoredInfo(this);
        predictInfo.open();
        predictInfo.getAvgMileage(this);
        predictInfo.close();
        try
        {
            predictKm = Long.parseLong(ETPredictKm.getText().toString());
            predictFuetlQty = Double.parseDouble(ETPredictFuelQty.getText().toString());



        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ne)
        {
            ne.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(isChkLastMileage1 ==true || isChkLastMileage5==true||isChkLastMileage10==true)
        {
        if(ETPredictKm.hasFocus())
            {
            ETPredictKm.setText("");
            if(predictFuetlQty!=0)
            {
                predictKm =(long) (predictionMileage*predictFuetlQty);
                //setPredictKm(predictKm);
                ETPredictKm.setText(String.valueOf(predictKm));
            }
            }
            else if(ETPredictFuelQty.hasFocus())
            {
                ETPredictFuelQty.setText("");
                if(predictKm!=0)
                {
                    predictFuetlQty =predictKm/predictionMileage;
                    //setPredictFuetlQty(predictFuetlQty);
                    ETPredictFuelQty.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(predictFuetlQty));
                }

            }   
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check a checkbox!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                ETPredictKm.setText("");
                                ETPredictFuelQty.setText("");
                                chkLastMileage1.setChecked(false);
                                chkLastMileage5.setChecked(false);
                                chkLastMileage10.setChecked(false);


    }
```

Comment: Ok so I just added finish() in my onclick() and everything seems to work fine except I have restart the activity everytime I click the "clear" button

Answer (score 0):

Add to your function.

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
editText.setText("");
```

Comment: I already tried doing that,when i check other checkbox the edittexts clear, but again when I click on the edittext to input new values the previous one appear.

Answer (score 0):

When you check the other checkbox do this

```
 edittext.setText("");
```

for other `EditText`

**Edit** -----

Add `FocusChangeListener` for all of your `EditText` and do this ----

```
ETPredictKm.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
        {
            if (hasFocus)
                ETPredictKm.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I already tried doing that,when i check other checkbox the edittexts clear, but again when I click on the edittext to input new values the previous one appear.

Comment: No dear, didnt work either. I have added a button "Clear" where I have set all edittexts and checkboxes to clear. But the same problem occurs. You think I can do something with the button then?

Answer (score 0):

If you store a reference to your editText you can just call

```
editText.setText("");
```

Do this inside your onCheckedChange listener when the checkbox is in your desired state.

Comment: I already tried doing that,when i check other checkbox the edittexts clear, but again when I click on the edittext to input new values the previous one appear.

Comment: Looking at your new code snippet it seems you have perhaps not fully understood the onCheckedChanged() method. This method is called each time the state of the checkbox changes, so that may be that it is unchecked or checked. At present it seems you aren't testing to see whether the box is checked or not and just assuming that it is.

Comment: You maybe need something like if(isPredictionChecked){ do what you need to do when checked} else { do what you need to do when they uncheck }

Comment: You say that when you select the editText fields the text that has previously been cleared from them appears again? You may need to provide more code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33860/discussion-between-pooja-gaonkar-and-scott-helme)

Answer (score 0):

Add a checkbox oncheckedchangelistener and then put edittest.setText(""); inside.

Do something like this:

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        edittext.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Also, don't forget to declare variables for your editexts, checkboxes, etc like this:

```
//example
final CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

Let me know if it works :)

Alternative:

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if ( checkbox.isChecked() )
            {
                edittext.setText("");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Iam also dealing with the SQLite database, If I declare the variables final I get errors :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with your oncheckedchangedlistener, try doing it like I showed you. Add oncheckedchangedlistener for every single checkbox. Or maybe try doing it like this, check my edit in a minute.

Comment: Did it work? This is exactly the kind of code I'm using for the same feature

Comment: Well it dous clear the edittext when I check the other checkboxes, but as soon as I click on the edit text to enter new data, the previous values appear again. I used finish() and everything works perfect but I need to start the activity all over again.

Comment: That really doesn't make any sense. Are you using shared preferences? Or maybe try clearing focus first?

Comment: No I am not using shared preferences. Also tried clearing focus but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

```
CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
Checkbox check2 = (Checkbox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
 if (check1.isChecked()) {
     EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_1);
     myEditText.setText("");
 }
 if (check2.isChecked()) {
     EditText myEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_2);
     myEditText1.setText("");
 }
```